# Reduce duplication in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using sqlplus to do a batch of inserts (unfortunately I can't use sqlldr). Each insert statement needs a value from another table like:

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, 'a', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'xyz') );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2, 'b', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'xyz') );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (3, 'c', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'xyz') );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (4, 'd', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'xyz') );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (5, 'e', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'mno') );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (6, 'f', (SELECT id FROM addressTab WHERE name = 'mno') );
```

The name is common for many inserts. How do I avoid requerying the `addressTab` for the same name again and again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up the data using a subquery or CTE:

```
insert into tab
    select d.x, d.y, a.id
    from (select 1 as x, 'a' as y, 'xyz' as name from dual union all
          . . .
          select 6, 'f', 'mno' from dual
         ) d join
         addressTab a
         on d.name = a.name;
```

If the first two values are coming from a table, then this is even easier.

By the way, when using `insert`, you should specify the names of the columns being inserted.  That helps prevent future problems.

Answer (score 0):

If source data is text file with delimeters, you can generate sql script with Excel or with regular expression.

Also you can load your source data into intermediate table. Then join this table with "address" table and   insert result in "tab" table.